# Can't display the function with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, ktikz

Hi I am trying to plot the following tikz code:

```
\def\tr{0.1}
\def\ts{0.6}
\def\al{1.3}
\def\n{1.6}
\def\I{0.3506}
\def\ti{0.4071}
\def\S{-0.1340}
\def\Sangle{-42}
\def\f1{0.8}

\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=-3:5, xscale=1, yscale=5, >=latex]
  \draw[very thin,color=gray!30] (-3,0)
    grid[xstep=0.5, ystep=0.1] (5,0.7);
  \draw[->, line width=1pt] (-3,0) -- (5.25,0)
    node[below] {$\log(\psi)$};
  \draw[->, line width=1pt] (-3,0) -- (-3,0.75)
    node[left] {$U(\psi)$};
  \draw[color=green!30!black, thick, smooth]
    plot[id=x, domain=-3:5]
    function{\tr+(\ts-\tr)/(1+(\al*exp(x))**\n)**(1-1/\n)};
  \node[left] (tr) at (-3,\tr) {$U_r$};
  \node[left] (ts) at (-3,\ts) {$U_s$};
  \draw[dashed] (\I,0) node[below] {$I$} -- (\I,\ti) -- (-3,\ti)
    node[left] {$U_i$};
  \draw[color=green!30!black, dashed]
    plot[id=x, domain=-1.5:3]
    function{\ti+\S*(x-\I)};
  \draw[|<->|] (\I,\ti)++(1,0) arc (0:\Sangle:0.8 and 0.15);
  \path (\I,\ti)++(0.5*1.5\Sangle/8:1)
    node[right=-1pt] {$\tan^{-1}(S)$};
  \node[anchor=base] (vg) at (1,0.8)
    {$U(\psi) = U_r+\displaystyle\frac{U_s-U_r}{(1+(\alpha\psi)^n)^m}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But for some reason, the function is not plotted I just get this:

[image]

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.  Also, if you are trying to do a graph you should consider `pgfplots` which is specifically designed for graphs.

Comment: As marmot indicates, when you do `plot function` TikZ actually outsources the computation of the function values to Gnuplot. So you a) need to have Gnuplot installed properly, and b) you need to run `pdflatex` with `--shell-escape` in order to allow `pdflatex` to execute other programs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, most likely you do not have the relevant software (gnuplot?) installed. But you don't need it, you can draw the functions with Ti*k*Z only.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\TR{0.1}
\def\TS{0.6}
\def\al{1.3}
\def\n{1.6}
\def\I{0.3506}
\def\ti{0.4071}
\def\S{-0.1340}
\def\Sangle{-42}
\def\fone{0.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=1, yscale=5, >=latex]
  \draw[very thin,color=gray!30] (-3,0)
    grid[xstep=0.5, ystep=0.1] (5,0.7);
  \draw[->, line width=1pt] (-3,0) -- (5.25,0)
    node[below] {$\log(\psi)$};
  \draw[->, line width=1pt] (-3,0) -- (-3,0.75)
    node[left] {$U(\psi)$};
  \draw[color=green!30!black, thick, smooth]
    plot[id=x, domain=-3:5]
    ({\x},{\TR+(\TS-\TR)/(1+(\al*exp(\x))^\n)^(1-1/\n)});
  \node[left] (tr) at (-3,\TR) {$U_r$};
  \node[left] (ts) at (-3,\TS) {$U_s$};
  \draw[dashed] (\I,0) node[below] {$I$} -- (\I,\ti) -- (-3,\ti)
    node[left] {$U_i$};
  \draw[color=green!30!black, dashed]
    plot[id=x, domain=-1.5:3]
    ({\x},{\ti+\S*(\x-\I)});
  \draw[|<->|] (\I,\ti)++(1,0) arc (0:\Sangle:0.8 and 0.15);
  \path (\I,\ti)++(0.5*1.5\Sangle/8:1)
    node[right=-1pt] {$\tan^{-1}(S)$};
  \node[anchor=base] (vg) at (1,0.8)
    {$U(\psi) = U_r+\displaystyle\frac{U_s-U_r}{(1+(\alpha\psi)^n)^m}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\endinput
```

[image]

Note that I used the opportunity to give some of your variables a safer name, e.g. `\tr` is really dangerous since it stands for trace, and so on. Note also that `def\f1{0.8}` does not do what you probably want, LaTeX does not accept numbers in macro names.